# Java - Exception to catch a Malformed Fraction

Tags: java

[image: image of code]

So long story short, the above code (part of a bigger program) should be should be able to catch an exception whenever the user inputs a malformed fraction such as (1/2/3). Now, the issue I'm running into is that my program is not catching the following "1/2/". Any suggestions on how can that part of the code be able to catch that type of malformed fraction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which code ? I do not see any code.

Comment: Please put the code snippet in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc of the single-argument [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method:

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

(emphasis mine)

If you want it to be included, you can use the [two-argument overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-). Replace `fraction.split("/")` with `fraction.split("/", 3)` and your behaviour is as expected. According to the Javadoc for this overload:

> If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times.

Since you want to catch if there is a second slash, you pass `3` as the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A fraction should only contain 1 forward slash (/) so simply check if there is only one forward slash and the fact that there is a numerical value on either side of it. If you use the **String.split("/")** method you know then that there should only ever be two array elements. It's now a matter of determining if the values within those elements are indeed string representations of numerical data. You can use the **String.matches()** method for that.

It would perhaps look something like this whereas:

It is assumed that:

- 0/2 is considered valid;
- 2/0 is considered Invalid.

In any case this assumtion can be modified:

```
public boolean isMalformed(String fraction) {
    boolean isMalformed = false;
    fraction = fraction.replace(" ", ""); //Remove any whitespaces
    String[] fractionValues = fraction.split("/");
    // It is assumed that: 0/2 is considered valid
    //                but: 2/0 is considered Invalid.
    if (fractionValues.length != 2 || 
        !fractionValues[0].matches("\\d+") || 
        !fractionValues[1].matches("\\d+") || 
        fractionValues[1].replace("0", "").equals("")) {
        isMalformed  = true;
    }
    return isMalformed;
}
```

You can see in the **String.matches()** method we use the [Regular Expression](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) **"\\d+"**, here is what this means:

[image]

Of course when you place a regex escape character (**\**) into a string you need to escape the escape character which is why you see two escape characters (**\\**) within the regular expression in code.